# Observable<boolean> not working

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs6

Could some one help me, because I am stuck in this function but is very important in the application.

**Typescript File**

```
get $approved(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.$entries.map(entries => {
    if (entries.length > 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      entries.every(entry => {
        return entry.approved != null;
      })
    }
  });
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<h1 *ngIf="$approved | async">PLANT</h1>
```

The problem is, that it will never show the H1 tag. And I don't have a clue why not.

Comment: Try to debug your code. What's the data in entries in the map function?

Comment: what version of rxjs you are using? if it's old use `return Observable.of(...)` if it rxjs 6 and above use `return of(...)`

Comment: Did you `subscribe` to start execute observer?

Comment: @VadimB the Async pipe do the subscription

Comment: What are you trying to do? please provide more background about the objects, and what they are filled with, and different scenarios so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` block never returns anything so the method only ever returns `false` or `undefined` which are both falsy. Update your code to return the result of the `every`:

```js
return entries.every(entry => {
  return entry.approved != null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever actually return the value if it is true in the code above. In the else block, you likely want:

```
return entries.every(entry => {
  return entry.approved != null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the value properly here:

```
entries.every(entry =>{ return entry.approved != null; })
```

Try something like this:

```
let result = false;
entries.every(entry =>{
  if (!result) result = (entry.approved != null) ? entry.approved : false;
});
return result;
```

A return statement inside a callback is not replicated to be the return for the outer method.  Closure doesn't work for return values.  The outer method must have the return statement.